# LightningChart DateTime axis not zooming to less than 1 day

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I'm trying to create a lightning chart using **lcjs.iife v3.4.0**. Its X axis is in **DateTime** format. I could not zoom the X axis to less than 1 day time limit using `axis.setInterval()` function. Bigger time limits are zoomed precisely.

What could be the reason?

#### chart.html

```html
<html>
<body>
    <style>
        button {padding: 10px; margin: 0 20px; font-size: 16px; color: green}
        button[error] {color: red}
    </style>
    <div id="trend-main-chart-container" style="width: 100%; height: 50%;"></div>
    <button onclick="resetXInterval(1)" error>Reset X Interval (1Hr)</button>
    <button onclick="resetXInterval(72)">Reset X Interval (3Days)</button>
    <button onclick="resetXInterval(168)">Reset X Interval (1Week)</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@arction/lcjs@3.4.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
<script>
    // Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
    const {
        lightningChart, Dashboard,
        SolidLine, SolidFill,
        ColorRGBA, ColorHEX, emptyFill, ColorCSS, UIElementBuilders, emptyLine,
        Themes, customTheme, UIBackgrounds, UIDirections,
        ColorPalettes, UILayoutBuilders, UIOrigins, UIVisibilityModes, MarkerBuilders,
        FontSettings, IndividualPointFill, translatePoint,
        AxisScrollStrategies, AxisTickStrategies, synchronizeAxisIntervals,
        AreaSeriesTypes, PointShape,
        AutoCursorModes,
    } = lcjs //Note: @arction/lcjs is not needed here, when using IIFE assembly
</script>

<script>
    const cssTextLite = '#eee'

    // Create XY chart
    const trendChartMain = lightningChart().ChartXY({
        theme: Themes.auroraBorealis,
        container: 'trend-main-chart-container',
        disableAnimations: true
    })
        .setMouseInteractions(false)
        .setAutoCursorMode(AutoCursorModes.disabled)

    // Configure Y axix
    const trendChartMainYAxis = trendChartMain.getDefaultAxisY()
    trendChartMainYAxis
        .setTitle('Title Y')
        .setTitleFont(new FontSettings({ size: 24, style: 'bold' }))
        .setTitleFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(cssTextLite) }))
        .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.fitting)
        .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric, tickStratergy =>  tickStratergy
            .setMajorTickStyle((tickStyle) => tickStyle
                .setLabelFont(new FontSettings({ size: 24, style: 'italic' }))
                .setLabelFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(cssTextLite) }))
            )
        )
        .setMouseInteractions(false)

    // Configure X axis ad DateTime axis
    const trendChartMainXAxis = trendChartMain.getDefaultAxisX()
        .setMouseInteractions(false)
        .setScrollStrategy()
        .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime)

</script>

<script>
    function resetXInterval(hrs) {
        trendChartMainXAxis.setInterval(
            // {hrs} before current time 
            new Date().getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * (hrs || 1)),
            // Current time 
            new Date().getTime()
        )
    }

    resetXInterval(100)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check out Time series section in LightningChart JS Developer documentation

https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/basic-topics/time-series-data/

Probably you can work with the first suggested solution there which is something like this:

```
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    defaultAxisX: {
        type: 'linear-highPrecision'
    }
})
```